# Better Templating for Grails

Tags: templates, grails

For all the things I love about Grails I do have one small issue and this isn't really even a Grails specific problem.  GSP changes require redeployments of the entire web application.  I'm not talking about adding new dynamic data or major changes.  These generally requires server side changes as well anyway.

But I'm talking about smaller changes like flipping the position of a couple of elements or modifying some simple static text on the page.  So my question is, what are some patterns used or plugins, etc that allow minor changes to GSP's without redeploying the entire application?  How can I make Grails template/GSP's more like templates and less requiring compiling?

I'm also possibly looking for something more designer friendly.

Answer (score 1):

[`grails.gsp.view.dir`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.6%20Making%20Changes%20to%20a%20Deployed%20Application), I think.

[A trick to remember](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GSP-reloading-in-production-mode-td2258219.html): add trailing slash and remember that `grails-app/views` will be added to it.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  While this is a step in the direction I want to go, it is not exactly what I'm looking for. Or at least, it doesn't feel entirely right.  Especially because of the permgen issue.

Comment: Your problem statement is "editing pages without redeploying". Recompiling any GSP requires more closures. You'll need some different views engine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Grails Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/freemarker) for using [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) templates as views (I have not used this plugin myself).  It is not listed as SpringSource supported, but I think the author is one the core grails devs and the plugin is based on a relatively new version of [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/).

Comment: Thanks, but Freemarker doesn't really solve the problem either.  It's doing the same thing with different types of tags.  Thanks though.

Comment: @Gregg The FreeMarker templates are not compiled and you can modify the ftl files on the server and see the changes immediately and I thought this was the problem you were trying to solve (not having to redeploy).    You can use the tag to render a FreeMarker template from within a GSP (changes to the template are dynamic) or you can use a FreeMarker template as the entire view itself in place of GSP.

Comment: True, but it is still a tag focused view. I probably should edit my question a bit.  I'd prefer something slightly more like Wicket views (but without the ick of Wicket) where it is more pure HTML.